# Getting type from std::integer_sequence pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

I'm trying to implement something to the effect of:

```
template <typename> struct integral_pack_traits;

template <template <template <typename T, T...> class> class Wrapper,
        template <typename T, T...> class P>
struct integral_pack_traits<Wrapper<P>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

so, for example, `std::index_sequence` will have typedef `std::size_t`.  Is this even possible?  Note that

```
template <typename Pack> struct integral_pack_traits;

template <template <typename U, U...> class P, typename T, T... Is>
struct integral_pack_traits<P<T, Is...>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

seems more fitting, but doesn't work for my application.  Here is my use case:

```
template <template <typename T, T...> class P> struct template_wrapper;

template <typename TemplateInfo> struct template_traits;

template <template <typename U, U...> class P>
struct template_traits<template_wrapper<P>> : 
    template_traits_h<template_wrapper<P>, std::integer_sequence<int>> { };
```

The `int` above needs to be replaced more generally with

```
integral_pack_traits<template_wrapper<P>>::type
```

in order to work correctly.

Comment: `std::integer_sequence::value_type`? It isn't very clear what your use case is, to be honest.

Comment: @ Passer By `P::value_type` does not compile because `P` is not a type.  I need to get the type from `P` itself given that all we have is `P`.

Comment: This is not even a meaningful question. It's the equivalent of "what's the value of `i` in `void f(int i);`?"